# HTML - Fixed div shows at position 0,0 only after scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed div, positioned `top 0` and `left 0`. It has the same width and height as the viewport. I show it on click on an element. It works great if I'm on the top of the page. If I scroll down a bit and perform the click, then the div is on the top left position of the page not on the screen, but if I scroll a little, then jumps to the expected position.
By default my div has `display: none` and on click I change it to `display: block`.

What can I do to my div at the top left position every time I click?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Ok, so I made a JSFiddle, it's not producing the exact bug, only a similar one, but it seems like it doesn't really like the changing background, because if I remove it, then it works perfectly.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthew3r/QUSm7/)

Comment: I moment, I will just remove what is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document.ready(function(){
  $("#mydiv").click(function(){
  $("#fixed").show()
  });

</script>`